# Can I use `Clang::CompilerInstance` to get llvm ir?

Tags: clang, llvm

Hi I've been searching on the internet but haven't found any answer.

What I would like to do is basically same as type the following command line in terminal and read the `alg5.bc` file as LLVM IR and then analyze it:

```bash
clang -emit-llvm -c './self_tests/src_huawei/alg5.cpp' -o 'alg5.bc' -O3 -fno-vectorize -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-unroll-loops
```

However, to avoid write, read and format transformation, I would like to do all of them by using clang/llvm APIs.

With my search, I can only find a possible way of using `Clang::CompilerInstance` to do that, but the detail is still not very clear to me.

Can anyone maybe provide a simple example of how to do it and explain the details?

Thanks a lot!!!